# ec2 instance url is showing files instead of running App

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, pm2

I have deploye react + node app in ec2 instance and installed pm2 to run the app in the background . 
When i ran *npm run build* and *server -s build*. Ec2 instance is running and app is accessible perfectly but i installed pm2 and ran the app using *pm2 start serve*
The app is runnig successfully
[image]

but when i access ec2 instance url i am getting file structure of the ec2 user instead of getting website

[image]

Everthing was working yesterday but suddenly it is showing like this ?
PLease check and give me your valuable feedback

Comment: i guess, you are not giving the path from where to serve, that is why, its serving all files from your project directrory statically.  check my answer may be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is lots of ways to build and serve.

`pm2 serve` does the static file serving.
command is `pm2 serve ./build <PORT>`
and also check if you are giving the folder path [i.e `./build` in here] from where it should serve.
make sure, you have already done `yarn build`.

---

***Way 1***

i guess you are serving it from the `./build` directory.
and it contains mostly static files,

so what you can do is, lets create a simple express server, which can serve those files from `./build`

add this file into you project directory:

**server.js**

```
const express = require("express");
const path = require("path");
const app = express();

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "build")));

app.get("/*", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "build", "index.html"));
});
const PORT =process.env.FRONT_PORT || 9000;
app.listen(PORT,()=>{
  console.log('listning at :' + PORT)
});
```

as you can see, in the above i have used `express.js` you have to install it too (`npm i express -S`).

now, you just go to the project directory, and start you app like this:
`pm2 start server.js --name <NAME OF THE AP>`

make sure, before you start with this abve command, do the build by using `yarn build` , which will create a build directory and we are using it inside the `server.js`.

---

***Way 2***

follow the above steps and add the `server.js` as well.
now lets automate the `yarn build` as well.

now create a `start.sh` file where the `server.js` is situating.

**start.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
yarn build && node ./server.js
```

you can run this by `pm2 start start.sh --name <APP NAME>`
and it will Build and run the server.js.

***NOTE:** this last process i.e with the yarn build may not possible in those instances, where cpu or resources are very low, like incase you are using `t.micro` or something.

Comment: chakraborthy Thank you very much

Comment: @Sravani you can also mark it as a right answer may be if it answered your query?

Comment: chakraborthy Done